# Sharing files and documents across computers and devices

Tags: ios

I often have multiple documents I am working on or need to keep on hand. This includes PDF, Word, Excel, Pages, etc. Sometimes I need to work on them on my Mac Mini or sometimes on my iPhone or iPad and I definitely need to view them on my iPhone and iPad.

What's the best "cloud-based" storage service for my situation?

Answer (score 4):

## [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)

When you put your files into your Dropbox folder, they're instantly available on any of your other computers that you've installed Dropbox on (Win, Linux, Mac).

There are also apps for iOS and Android available. The Dropbox app for iOS is able to display pdfs and office documents. You cannot edit them, tough.

- You get **2GB for free**. 250MB for every friend you invite (8GB limit, though). If you pay, you can get even more space.
- **Growl** integration for sync notification updates.
- **Web interface**.
- You can **share folders** with other people while keeping other folders private.
- Create **download links** to your contents.

Comment: Curse you gentmatt! I was about a minute away from completing my write up!

(But, good answer :).)

Comment: @JasonSalaz Haha! I was sure there were other people going to write this as well. Therefore, I was writing this answer in a hurry. :)

Comment: Getting the answer out and then editing more content in is probably the better idea in blanket situations like this. I will keep that in mind for next time.

You win this round, next time, we race :).

Comment: Have you tried any other services? Why is this your particular favorite? And it seems you both like it - so would love to hear both of your perspectives on it.

Comment: I‘ve tried **[SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/)** aswell. You get 5GB free and 500MB for every invite. I declined it‘s use because the I did not like the GUI and the [iOS client](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sugarsync/id288491637?mt=8).  However, regarding the app store ratings, I should give another try maybe?